# Should linked questions be more visible?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, advertising, linked-questions, sidebar

Every now and then I remember that there are actually links to other questions on the right hand side. For people who don't know: Whenever you post a URL to another question, the question that links the other will be listed on the right hand side of the target question:

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

[image]

As you can see, linked questions are not very prominent on that page and I really wish they were!

There are several reasons why I think these links should be more visible on a questions' page:

- Users might find related questions faster
- Users might become encouraged to link related questions more often
- It's more natural (imo) to see linked questions *before* blogs or job offers

This issue came to my mind a few times in the past already and I finally took the time to bring it up on meta.

What do people think about this?

I really think that we're missing some potential here.

Comment: Well, the ads push it down a LOT. Legit business decision of course, but good point.

Comment: Considering ads are the reason they're down so far, the alternative would be making it wider. Which leaves less screen real-estate for even more important parts. So, I think leaving it be is actually the best option here. Unless they're willing to remove that useless piece of white on the left of the screen...

Comment: @Shadow9 Yes, I guess the ads are a necessity. I am not a (good) UI designer but I'd see the left hand side as a place where these links could be? I just wanted to bring it up because even though I _know_ they are there, I keep forgetting they are and forget to look for them every now and then.

Comment: Left sidebar is for navigation, while Linked Questions are links, it's not really part of the site navigation itself, so not sure it fits.

Comment: @Mast Honestly, I think they could change places with the list of blog posts. If I land on a question and it's not what I was looking for, I'd look to the right and see if there are question titles which might sound right for me.

Comment: @Shadow9 There's probably a good reason why the leave so much space on the left side. I just wanted to bring it up in a discussion - maybe people have some ideas.

Comment: @Shadow9 I was actually thinking of shrinking that piece of white, not putting the links there.

Comment: Of-course, if the ads are too far down, an ad-blocker does fix that. Not saying that's a good idea, but it *does* work.

Comment: @Mast I usually turn off the ad blocker for pages I want to support :D

Comment: I have created a Brower extension which might solve this issue and provide additional features - following are the links [Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-me-first/pmjhehdfjfahnlgdblnhhfcimegodmnj), [Microsoft Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/stack-me-first/andilefigneejkadafmdfcmjdnabfbhi) & [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stack-me-first/)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it should be more visible.

My suggestion: add a link to the existing list on top of the question, besides the Asked, Active, and Viewed stats:

> [image: Mockup with link to linked questions]

This isn't intrusive, doesn't clutter the page, and clicking it will auto scroll to the proper location.

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea actually!

Comment: But doesn't this give the linked question more prominence than they need? The fact that a question has or hasn't links is honestly irrelevant to see as a stat. The biggest problem is that "linked" is quite sketchy to begin with - posting the URL to another question *in a comment* will link the two...but if the comment was responding to something else, so it's not relevant *to the question* but rather to a different context. Dropping the comment leaves the link, too, so you now have a link but it serves nobody looking at the question itself.